# error: there was a problem with the editor "vi" -- while trying to change deployment file

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, terminal, macvim, macos

Facing this error **error: there was a problem with the editor "vi"** when trying to change a deployment file in the Kubernetes cluster (AKS)

`kubectl edit deploy xxxxx -o yaml`

upon exiting the file, the above error is thrown with no changes applied.

Few screenshots...

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is pretty thin on details but what about the E363 error in the lower screen shot? When Vim encounters this error it "mostly behaves like CTRL-C was typed". It's impossible to be sure based on the information provided but it could be that if you fix source of the E363 then kubernetes won't have anything to complain about anymore.

Comment: (Even if that has nothing to do with the stated problem it doesn't seem like a good idea to let that error keep occurring! `:h E363`)

Comment: How do we fix this E363?

Comment: Did you read the documentation I referenced? Nothing more I can tell you than to start by reading that.

Comment: probably an expansive yaml-syntax pattern. Try increasing the maxmempattern and maxmemtotal memory. Also Vim version may matter

Comment: [Please do not post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)